# Pure Data pix_film filmQT: Could not initialize quicktime

Tags: puredata

I'm using Pd-extended on Microsoft Windows.
When trying to put the object `[pix_film]`,
I get this error:

> filmQT: Could not initialize quicktime: error -2093

What is the problem? How to fix it?

I really need video functionality, as I'm learning how to use this for an art show.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1875

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically Gem on windows and OS X requires Apple's QuickTime (on linux: libquicktime) for objects using this framework. Current versions remove this dependency by offering other frameworks alternatives, for instance [gmerlin](http://gmerlin.sourceforge.net/avdec.html), as *plugins*.

Install Apple QuickTime on your Windows, that should fix the error mentioned.

Comment: well, no there is no GStreamer based film-backend. but you are right that QuickTime (`filmQT`, which btw is unrelated to the libquicktime-based `filmQT4L`) is only usable if you have Apple's QuickTime installed.